# How do I combine two different arrays and sort them properly based on number of occurrences?

Tags: php, arrays

I have some simple php code that allows me to find the top number of registered users from a the most active zip codes and by extension, the most active state.  However I want to find the most active counties.  The problem is that the same county name are used in multiple states, so you don't want to add them together.

```
$sql_top_zips="SELECT zipcode FROM user_list WHERE TRIM(zipcode) != '' ";
$test_results = mysqli_query( $link , $sql_top_zips );
while ($test_check = mysqli_fetch_array($test_results)) 
{     
    $top_zips   =   $test_check["zipcode"];
    $details = $z->get_zip_details($top_zips);

    $county[]= $details['county'];
    $states[]= $details['state_name'];
}
$top_county = array_count_values($county);
arsort($top_county);
$x=0;
foreach($top_county as $results=>$counter) {
    echo $results."<br>";
    $x++;
    if ($x==5) {break;}
}
```

So using this simple code I can create a list of the top 5 counties. If you use print_r() for an array view you can see `Array ( [Madison] => 4 [Davidson] => 3 [Harris] => 2 [Grant] => 1 [Morgan] => 1)` with some demo data.  So this works fine.

But if somebody is in Jackson County, which occurs more than 20 times across the usa, then you get a false number because you are actually talking about different Jackson counties.

I thought my solution was to try this:

```
$test[]=$details['county']['state_name'];
$testb=array_count_values($test);
arsort($testb);
```

But I use print_r() something odd like this instead:  `Array ( [M] => 6 [D] => 4 [H] => 3 [L] => 2 [U] => 2 [R] => 2 [P] => 1 )`

My goal is to list the county names with states, like this:  `Jackson TN, Jackson MS` but as the most frequently ocuring.  I feel that I'm close to a solution but I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concatenation is incorrect.  Try something like this…

```
$test[]=$details['county'] . " " . $details['state_name'];
```

Comment: That'll just produce an array of counties and states, duplicate counties and states won't be together, they'll be repeated.

Comment: @Styphon, OP then runs `$testb=array_count_values($test);` on the result of the above.

Comment: I actually tried `$test[]=$details['county'] . " " . $details['state_name'];` before posting the question.  No luck there.

Comment: @Maelish Could you please explain 'No luck there'?  What exactly were the results?  See this simple example I wrote up  http://3v4l.org/QkLJr

Comment: My apologies, a simple typo was causing failure.  Its amazing what a night of sleep will allow you to see.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, what you need to do is use the county and state as the key in your array. Something like this should help:

```
$array = array();
while ($test_check = mysqli_fetch_array($test_results)) {
    $details = $z->get_zip_details($test_check["zipcode"]);
    $key = $detail['county'] . ' ' . $details['state_name'];
    //If we've not encountered this county in this state, we initiate it in the array, starting the count at 0.
    if(!isset($array[$key])) {
        $array[$key] = 0;
    }
    $array[$key]++;
}
asort($array);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: I'm missing something simple again, what is the $array?

Comment: $array is just a variable containing everything. Call that whatever you want. I think you called it $testb in your example above.